# Scrape API service for multiple users with Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, express, web-scraping

I need to create a service that **scrapes** a 3rd party site using the cookies/session of each user that makes the request.

I need this service to handle **only 1 request at the time** and then put the other requests in **queue**, because I want to avoid the users getting flagged or banned and my server from getting blocked.

For this purpose I was naively using `setTimeout`s to hardcode delays between each `GET` and `POST` request that my server made.

After a moment I remembered that *NodeJS* is async by nature and doesn't offer a way to handle threads right away. I'm not sure if the `setTimeout`s are doing what I'm thinking because my server is not pausing for the time I coded the `setTimeout`s between `GET` and `POST` requests to the *3rd party server*.

**Is NodeJS a good fit for this?**

**How can I code it in my Express server?**

**What are my alternatives?**

**Can you provide an example?**

Comment: is async.queue relevant for this use case?